# Is there a way to customize the Android Ringtone Picker Dialog?

Tags: android, customization, ringtone

I show a dialog for selecting one of the native ring tones / text tones with the following code:

```
private void showTonePicker(int toneType, String pickerTitle) {
[...]
```

`Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);`

```
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, toneType);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, pickerTitle);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_DEFAULT, true);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, userTone.equals(TFSettings.SILENT_TONE_ID) ? null : Uri.parse(userTone));
    startActivityForResult(intent, (toneType == RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE ? 1 : 2));
}
```

I call the above method like this:

- for selecting text tone: 
  showTonePicker(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION, getString(R.string.texting_tone));
- for selecting ring tone: 
  showTonePicker(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, getString(R.string.ringing_tone));

I have two problems to solve:

1. I must show lower cased buttons
2. In both cases (i.e. when selecting ring tone and also when selecting text tone), the native dialof shows "Default ringtone". I must display "Default text tone" in case of selecting a text tone (in this case toneType = RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION).

Is there a way to resolve these? Can we customize the native tone picker?

Thanks for the answers in advance!

Regards.

Comment: Is there a way to preselect the default ring / text (notifcation) tone?  "intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_DEFAULT_URI, Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI);" seems to not work.

Comment: I had the same problem and I cannot believe that no one know the answer, though it's so common task. Didn't you find answer yet?

Answer (score 0):

To set default ringtone, you have to set EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI first.

```
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, ringtoneUri);
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_DEFAULT_URI, ringtoneUri);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can we customize the native tone picker?

No, sorry, not with respect to the items that you describe. You would need to build your own UI for this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's possible. Besides, there is no guarantee the RingtonePreference is going to open the System's ringtone picker. The user might have another app installed that has an activity with the [android.intent.action.RINGTONE_PICKER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html#ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER) intent filter declared in the manifest and he might even have it as the default Ringtone picker.

You might implement a custom RingtonePreference and a custom RingtonePickerActivity and force your custom Ringtone picker to be open but you might irritate your users.

If I may ask, for what reason would you like to change it anyway?